# How to view JSON from FB Messenger & how to store lat/long in vars

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using Google Cloud Platform with Dialogflow to deploy my bot. I am asking Facebook users to send their location and I have my follow up intent with the event "FACEBOOK_LOCATION" and I have "Use Webhook" checked under fulfillment using Node. All of this works fine, except for the fact that I have no clue how to view the JSON response at this point. This is then obviously problematic because I'm unsure of how to actually grab the Lat & Long from the response to eventually use them in the API call I want to make further along the conversation. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can take lat and long value as a parameter in Dialogflow and when you call webhook from the Dialogflow you will get the lat and lng value in the parameter list.